# Change in the mass of a star due to nuclear fussion of Hydrogen

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics, astrophysics

Let's suppose a star is initially composed only of hydrogen. After a certain time $t$, it has consumed the $5\%$ of its initial hydrogen, fusing it to produce helium, according to the following reaction:

$$4 H^1 \rightarrow He^4 +\Delta E$$

I'm trying to find out the ratio of the initial mass $M$ and the mass after the fussion of the 5% of the initial Hydrogen, $M/M'$.

**My attempt**

Assuming that this nuclear reaction is the only one that occurs, if initially there were $N_H$ attoms of Hydrogen and no attoms of Helium, then after the $5\%$ of the H is fussed, there will be $N'_H=0.95N_H$ and $N'_{He}=\frac{0.05}{4}N_H$. However, since the mass of H is 1 a.m.u. and the mass of He is 4 a.m.u.,

$M'=(0.95N_H·1 + \frac{0.05}{4}N_H·4)\text{ u.m.a.}=N_H\text{ u.m.a.}=M$

Therefore, does the mass remain constant during the process of nuclear fussion of Hydrogen?

Answer (score 1):

If the atomic mass of $^4\text{He}$ were exactly $4$ times the atomic mass of $^1\text H$ then $\Delta E$ would be zero and the mass of the star would be constant (and we would not be here to think about this problem). However, the atomic mass of $^4\text{He}$ is slightly less than $4$ times the atomic mass of $^1\text H$, so ...

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not. Using AMUs rounded to the nearest integer to measure mass in this reaction is insufficiently precise to catch the actual mass difference m, which is radiated away as energy by E= mc^2.